# Why doesn't Spider-Man look like an adult in Captain America: Civil War?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

I don't understand why Spider-Man doesn't look like an adult in Captain America: Civil War?

Is it something to do with the Marvel timeline or what?

Comment: Are you by any chance confusing Spider-man from civil war with previous spider-man films?

Comment: Why should he? Spider-Man is a highschooler.

Comment: Important to note that the previous Spiderman / Amazing Spiderman movies were NOT part of the MCU.  Civil War (and the new Homecoming) are.  So, the character is being rebooted *yet again.*

Comment: Because he's a teenager

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it something to do with timeline or what?

No, it seems to do something with director's choice.

The director of Civil Wars, [Joe Russo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo_brothers), wanted someone who is more of an authenticity to the casting. He is a high-school superhero, making him different from other characters in Marvel Universe. Therefore, they wanted to cast someone who is close to high-school age.

Here is an excerpt of [the interview of him](http://comicbook.com/2016/01/08/exclusive-captain-america-civil-war-directors-explain-how-their-/)(emphasis mine).

> "We took a very personal approach to the character," explained Joe Russo. "He was my favorite character growing up, so the opportunity to bring Spider-Man to the screen is a dream come true. It's something that I spent a lot of time thinking about as a kid. We had thought back to the things that excited us about him as a character when we were younger, and **one of the most important components of that was that he's a high schooler burdened with incredible powers and responsibility. That really differentiates him from every other character in the Marvel universe as opposed to other superheroes.**
>
> **For us, it was extremely important that we cast somebody very close to the age of a high school student. The previous films had adults playing a high schooler. We wanted more of an authenticity to the casting.** We were very specific about that. **We wanted an energy and charisma from the character, an energy, but also an insecurity that would make him fun to watch in contrast to the confident superheroes.**

Comment: A clarification that this Spider Man is a reboot compared to all previous cinematic Spider Men would improve this answer.